# Wordpress not showing sidebar widget when logged out

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My site is ignoring sidebar items when we are logged out, so the end users don't see a banner and other items. It only shows up when I'm logged in. I have no idea where to go to next, there are no PHP errors when debug is enabled, the footer is correct.

Logged out:

[image: End user]

Logged in:

[image: Administrator]

Comment: which theme are you using. its a theme issue.